# Zeppelin with Shiro backed permissions to create/modify notebooks

Tags: apache-zeppelin

How do I specify role permissions on Shiro so that only the `admin` role/user can create and modify notebooks and the `client` role/user has only read permissions?

I know that I can specify per notebook permissions but:

- I'd have to manually add all `client` users to reader-only in every notebook created by `admin` users. Too much trouble, at best I could create a single `client` user, but I'd still have to include it in every notebook permission manually.
- Even if I take the time to do as above, I don't know how to prevent `client` users (or the `client` user) from creating notebooks.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: @1ambda currently 0.6.2., but I'd accept anything that works on 0.7+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps you outlined are correct. Even if you add `client` to readers of every notebook, controlling note creation still would be a problem. These issues related to more fine grained notebook authorisation are currently being developed in Zeppelin, and I believe this issue under [ZEPPELIN-1608](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1608) is related to your requirements. I'd suggest to comment there with your use case and vote up/watch the issue, so that it will have higher chances of being addressed in near future by the community.

Comment: Great. ZEPPELIN-385 also seems promising, and there's already a PR for that. Thanks :-)